# Как присвоить данные AR модели к ActiveForm?

Tags: php, yii

Есть представление, в котором идет вывод `ActiveForm` и если в базе есть заполненные данные, вставляются ранее введенные данные в форму. Сейчас я присваиваю данные модели к `Activeform` вот так:

```
foreach ($user->attributes as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $af->attributes))
        $af->$key = $value;
}
```

На мой взгляд, это неудобно и медленно. Как средствами Yii можно по другому выполнить эту операцию?

Comment: а что Вам мешает создать модель, выполнить по ней поиск и сразу отправить данные во view?
Например:
$model = Posts::model()->findByPk($id);
$this->render('manage',array('model'=>$model));

Таким образом все поля в ActiveForm будут заполнены

Comment: а чем медленно и неудобно то? 

Comment: ну во первых надо передавать актив форм так как строится там форма и в ней сразу заполняются данные если они уже есть. Медленно тем что по моим тестам этот метод в 10 раз медленнее CMap::merge_array(). Неудобно тем что это все таки не одна строчка. CMap::merge_array неудобен тем что на выходе я получаю массив который не могу присвоить нормально к ActiveForm... Надеюсь вы меня поняли...

Answer (score 1):

```
$cmodel->attributes = $cactiveform->attributes;
```

Не присваиваются только поля которые не валидируются и не помечены как safe остальные все присваиваются через attributes корректно.